# Require true if only one pair of outer parenthesis is present (using Regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var reg=/[\(\d{3}\)]/g;
(reg).test(str); //
```

the above code is `true` for any number of parenthesis `str="(((555)))"`, `str="((555))"`.
I want `true` only when there is only one pair of parenthesis `str="(555)"` and for any other `string` it should be `false`;

Comment: Do you mean `var reg=/^\(\d{3}\)$/`? Match a string that starts with `(`, 3 digits, and then ends with `)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew starts with (,then 3 digits and then ) and can't ever have any surrounding characters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are unclear on the [character class operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html).  For what you have asked, you want to anchor at the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string, and you want to find a parenthesis (`\(`) followed by 3 digits (`\d{3}` or `\d\d\d`) followed by a final parenthesis (`\)`).  Altogether:

```
var reg = /^\(\d{3}\)$/;
```

You were close, just needed to swap the brackets with the anchors.

Comment: More, you do not even need `g` here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good point.  I must have copy pasted!  I'll just fix that ...